# concurrency in AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, aws-lambda, concurrency

I am just looking for confirmation that I understand the lambda settings correctly.
The minimum concurrency setting is 10, My lambda function takes 3000 ms.
So does that mean the maximum number of times my function can be called a minute is...

60 seconds / 3 seconds = 20 calls

20 x 10 concurrent = 200 function calls per minute.

thanks

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: thanks thats good news.